# How to print time in exact UTC format "2015-05-28T22:55:00:000Z" in python27

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, utc

I need to see output in above-mentioned format. I tried:

1. `datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-4]`
2. `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f')[:-4]`

it does not include `Z` at the end.

Comment: Why not just add a `'Z'`, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Z`

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f')[:-4] + 'Z'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I may have missed think this way